# How can I change color of background using a group of radio buttons?

Tags: java, swing

Could you please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly in this code? Purpose of this code is simple - change color of background depending upon user selection of 1 of 3 radio buttons.

I gave up on changing the background color of frame, and tried replacing the background color of an additional panel that i threw on top of the frame.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

```
public Ch16_Frame() { initComponents(); } 
// this calls method generated automatically using NetBeans GUI Builder. It is simply declaring properties of Swing objects.

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Ch16_Frame test = new Ch16_Frame();
            test.setVisible(true);
            test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            test.colorChooser();
        }
    });
}

public void colorChooser() {
    // Color chooser
    if (redBackground.isSelected()) {
        backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    else if (blueBackground.isSelected()) {
        backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
    else if (greenBackground.isSelected()) {
        backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE]. Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool. For all we know, you may not even be adding your backgroundPanel to the GUI, or its size might be minuscule.

Comment: I am using Netbeans GUI builder so the code is automatically generated for that. I've reviewed rest of code, and I have a strong feeling that there's an error in the code that I copied above. Do you believe that code is error-free?

Comment: The code copied above is not fully relevant to your problem. You're lucky that someone was able to guess well, but in the future, you may not be so lucky and you'll want to strive to ask a more complete question, including posting your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing comes to mind. You do not seem to have implemented any actionlisteners. You have methods that check which radiobutton is selected, but you need to implement a listener, who actually triggers an action when the radiobuttons are pressed. This requires a bit of reading, but I hope this will give you the nudge you need to move on.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: You're correct. I haven't implemented that. The fact that I call colorChooser() method in main doesn't eliminate it's need?

Comment: Here's the thing. Your main method first creates the frame, right? Then it does a couple of other things, and then it checks the radiobuttons. Once. It will never check them again after that, even if you click them. Unless you also set a radiobutton before calling the checkColor-method, it will be done checking long before you click any of them, and after that, it will not care.

Comment: Also, action listeners can be a bit confusing. At least I struggled a little bit with them for a while. I got good at it, but I haven't done java swing in some years now, so I do not remember the syntax. And you need to learn it yourself anyway. Just don't give up :)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I am using Murach's Java book and they haven't covered this yet, however, this is not a book exercise either. I'll learn about Action Listeners and that should resolve this issue. While I have your attention, I'd like to ask another question. How would I change the color of the frame in that colorChooser() method instead of needing to add another panel?

Comment: Feel free to tag my name in a comment on your new question. I'll be hanging around for a few more minutes, but it is past midnight in Central Europe, so I need to sleep soon ;)

Comment: I asked my question in my previous comment.